# How can I add a JPopupMenu to the title bar of JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpopupmenu

I need to modify/add a `JPopupMenu` to the titlebar of a `JFrame`.
I did that with `JInteralFrame` using a method from the `JComponent` class called `insert(cmponent, index)`.

Is there something similar for a `JFrame`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how can i change the color of titlebar in JFrame?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2482971/how-can-i-change-the-color-of-titlebar-in-jframe)

Comment: they are duplicates from the prospective of the problem, as the answer there is the same for this as well::

ts not possible. The top level JFrame is controlled by the look & feel of the underlying OS.

You CAN change the color(PopupMenu) of an InternalFrame.