# How to change title color of dialog from white to any other color

Tags: android

In my code `dialog2.setTitle("FeedBack");` is shown in a white color. How do I change title change color? Because my layout background is white so I can't see it. How do I change dialog title color?

```
public Dialog dialog2;
    ImageView b = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    dialog2 = new Dialog(context);
    View vLoad = LayoutInflater.from(fifthscreen.this).inflate(R.layout.timer, null);

    dialog2.setContentView(vLoad);
     dialog2.setTitle("FeedBack");
     dialog2.setCancelable(false);
    dialog2.show();
    }
    });

   }


       ////////////timer.xml///////////


              <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:background="#ffffff"

 android:id="@+id/layouttimer">


      <TextView
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:textSize="15dp"
    android:textColor="#000000" ></TextView>




<Button
    android:id="@+id/FeedbackYummiSlice"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text=" YumiiSlice" >

</Button>


<Button
    android:id="@+id/FeedbackThisdish"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="   Feedback This dish   " >
</Button>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/nothanks"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="          No,Thanks          " >

</Button>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Please refer the following post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2482971/how-can-i-change-the-color-of-titlebar-in-jframe

Comment: what link u give? is not understanding

Answer (score 0):

The method `setCustomTitle(View customTitleView)` allows you to do that. You need to create a layout to set in this, and in that layout simply set to the TextView the style you want.

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View customTitleView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_title_view, null);

AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
.setCustomTitle(customTitleView);
```

Please refer [This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15285514/1405983) for more information.

Comment: i alrready create a view check this line    View vLoad = LayoutInflater.from(fifthscreen.this).inflate(R.layout.timer, null); and load in content view

Comment: @user2867267 Create view for title(TextView) and set it using setCustomTitle.

Comment: but problem is imnot using Alert dailog im justing simple dialog check my code

Comment: You can do it with Dialog also. check this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/15273468/1405983