# JFrame Change Border Color

Tags: java, swing, methods, jframe

Hey ho everybody  I need some help
I want to change the Color from my JFrame
I know that I can remove the border with "setUndecorated(true)"
but now I want to customize this Border.
Are there any methods to customize my JFrame border??
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Google before you ask. Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2482971/how-can-i-change-the-color-of-titlebar-in-jframe

Comment: The best choice is to create a Look And Feel delegate for the frame, and probably set it's [`DefaultLookAndFeelDecorated`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(boolean)) to `true`

Comment: @ChristopheDeTroyer Hmmm, not entirely true (linked answer), it is possible, may not be what the OP wants to do though ;)

Comment: I google before but there are only themes like How can I change my backgound or something like this and thats not what I searched for.
But thank You for Your response @Christophe De Troyer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a LAF:

```
try {
        // Set cross-platform Java L&F (also called "Metal")
    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(
        UIManager.getCrossPlatformLookAndFeelClassName());
} 
catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e) {
   // handle exception
}
catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
   // handle exception
}
catch (InstantiationException e) {
   // handle exception
}
catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
   // handle exception
}
```

this wil use the default look and feel for youre divice. 
You can download custom lafs from the web

Comment: This won't use "the default look and feel for your divice", you'd need to use the system look and feel. This will use the cross platform (metal) look and feel, wch, IMHO is crap