# Change JOption Border color

Tags: java, swing

I wan to make my JOption's Border to be Black color. As you can see, its default color is blue. The blue color is required to be change to Black. I tried

```
JOptionPane optionPane = new JOptionPane(...., 
    JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
 final JDialog dialog = optionPane.createDialog(parentComponent, title);
 dialog.getRootPane().setBorder( BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.Black) );
```

Is there any way to do this ?

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2482971/how-can-i-change-the-color-of-titlebar-in-jframe.it might be impossible .you can change color of title bars by changing windows settings.you can use undercoated dialog box with your own title bar

Comment: @FastSnail. Thanks for the Link. As its answers mention, there is no way to do it, because the border is controlled by the OS / native colors ?