# Making the title bar transparent in Java

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, jframe

Here's what my program looks like so far:
[image]

Is there any way to make that gray title bar on the top transparent?

I tried `setUndecorated()` but that completely removes the red/yellow/green window buttons and doesn't let me drag the window around.

Incase you don't understand what I'm asking, in Objective C I was able to make the titlebar transparent in this program:

[image: Images]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how can i change the color of titlebar in JFrame?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2482971/how-can-i-change-the-color-of-titlebar-in-jframe)

Comment: It's not really possible to do this in Java, at least not without a lot work and hacking and native code

Answer (score -1):

You can use JFrame.setOpacity() and set a percentage from 0 to 1 to make the entire frame translucent. Then set the contents to opaque. More information [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/trans_shaped_windows.html).

Comment: Sounds cool but I get the error `Exception in thread "main" java.awt.IllegalComponentStateException: The frame is decorated`. I made sure to put it before the `setVisible` call but it still didn't work.

Comment: The OP doesn't want to make the window transparent

Comment: It seems like the frame must be undecorated in newer java versions for transparency to work. you can try the following: this.setUndecorated(true);
this.getRootPane().setWindowDecorationStyle(JRootPane.FRAME);  to remove the original title bar and create another one within the rootpane of the frame