# Windows Builder java ECLIPSE, how to set the Background of JFrame's top?

Tags: java, eclipse, background, jframe

Help, the background option doesn't work. I don't know how to do this.

I don't know how to set the background color of the `JFrame`'s top.

[image: How to set the BG of the JFrames top]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how can i change the color of titlebar in JFrame?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2482971/how-can-i-change-the-color-of-titlebar-in-jframe)

Comment: If you are using the system look and feel, you can't