# Override windows theme with java LookAndFeel

Tags: java, windows, colors, title

I am trying to change the windows borders of my application. The aim is to be independent from the Windows theme of the user.
For that I use the already implemented LookAndFeel class of my company but I don't find the correct attribute which I should change the color.

My last try is with InternalFrame but it doesn't work.

```
putComponentColor("InternalFrame.activeTitleBackground", new ColorUIResource(30, 144, 255));
putComponentColor("InternalFrame.inactiveTitleBackground", new ColorUIResource(30, 144, 255));
```

You can see below the orange windows theme that I put. It should be override in blue.

[image: Orange windows theme, title color]

What is the attribute to change the windows title color?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how can i change the color of titlebar in JFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2482971/how-can-i-change-the-color-of-titlebar-in-jframe)

Comment: I already looked at this post, but it says to use InternalFrame. It is the attribute I showed it doesn't work in my case.

Comment: My point is it says, _**Its not possible**. The top level JFrame is controlled by the look & feel of the underlying OS._

Comment: But is there anyway even by a property file, or a java launch option to override the OS look and feel?