# JetBrains Compose for Desktop title bar background color or dark mode

Tags: compose-desktop, compose-multiplatform

Is there a way in JetBrains Compose for Desktop to change the title bar background color or just change it for dark mode? I'm using MacOS, so the bar can be light or dark. It would also be fine to make titlebar itself invisible (but keep the close, minimise and maximise buttons) and create your own view below it.

I was looking in the compose window code, but couldn't find it there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Compose is build on top of Swing, and it [doesn't seems possible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2512838/3585796) to change the title bar color.

But at least you can follow system dark/light mode with the following option in your `build.gradle.kts`:

```
compose.desktop {
    application {
        // ...
        nativeDistributions {
            // ...
            jvmArgs(
                "-Dapple.awt.application.appearance=system"
            )
        }
    }
}
```

An other option is building your own title bar, like shown in [this tutorial](https://github.com/JetBrains/compose-jb/tree/master/tutorials/Window_API_new#draggable-window-area), but this will also hide the system buttons, which is far from perfect.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Too bad it's not possible, would've loved just a dark title bar. But the jvmArgs is nice and could be set to dark instead of system as well, didn't know that could be done. It's hard to find resources about it. The thing I found as well is `putClientProperty("apple.awt.fullWindowContent", true)` `putClientProperty("apple.awt.transparentTitleBar", true)` `putClientProperty("apple.awt.windowTitleVisible", false)`. Which will make it invisible, but keeps the system buttons. If I or you or somebody else finds the answer I'll wait for a bit, otherwise I will accept yours

Answer (score 1):

check [this](https://github.com/amir1376/compose-custom-window-frame) for custom title bar

I wrote this to solve my problem in windows
but you should get the idea

I hope jetbrains team  provide a solution out of the box

### Update

Also check [Jetbrains Jewel](https://github.com/JetBrains/jewel)

It seems they used native buttons (for windows and mac ,but linux buttons are custom) as I read their code

Comment: Looks very good, but I'd prefer to use the default mac buttons and rather not create my own. But otherwise nicely done!

Comment: @KevinvanMierlo I updated my answer maybe could help

Comment: Good find! This is great! Looks like I only need TitleBar with decorated window. Never knew it could be so easy! I was really struggling with adjusting the title bar, so hopefully this will solve it

Answer (score 0):

Building on the tutorial referenced in the above answer, I created an extension function to the `DialogWindowScope` and added it as the first element in an undecorated `Dialog`

````
Dialog(...) {
    Column (...) {
        dialogTitleBar("dialog title") { on close clicked }
    }
}

@Composable
fun DialogWindowScope.dialogTitleBar(
    title: String? = null,
    onClick: () -> Unit
) = WindowDraggableArea{
    Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
        Row(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween,
            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
        ) {
            Text(
                modifier = Modifier.padding(start = 10.dp, bottom = 4.dp, top = 4.dp),
                color = MaterialTheme.colors.primary,
                fontSize = MaterialTheme.typography.body2.fontSize,
                text = title ?: ""
            )

            CloseButton(onClick)
        }
        Divider(
            Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
            color = MaterialTheme.colors.primary.copy(alpha = .95f)
        )
    }
}

@Composable
fun CloseButton(onClick: () -> Unit) {
    val interactionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() }
    val isHovered by interactionSource.collectIsHoveredAsState()
    Icon(
        modifier = Modifier.size(24.dp)
            .background(if (isHovered) Color.Red else MaterialTheme.colors.onPrimary)
            .hoverable(interactionSource)
            .clickable(onClick = onClick),
        imageVector = Icons.Default.Close,
        contentDescription = "Close",
        tint = MaterialTheme.colors.primary
    )
}```
````